# jquery event function to element that was added using .append()

Tags: jquery, append

I have a function that appen some html code to my already existing div like so:

```
<div id="my_ok_div">
<span>click me</span>
<div class="okay">ok</div>
</div>
```

jQuery to add divs:

```
$('#my_ok_div').click(function(){
$('#my_ok_div').append('<div class="okay">bla</div><div class="okay">bla bla</div>');  
});
```

also I have a function that work with div with class okay

```
$('.okay').click(function(){
  alert('all okay!'); 
})
```

this perfectly work for already existed div with class okay that contains "ok" word.
But, this not working for appended divs. Why and how i can fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either bind (or rebind) the event when you call `.append`, or you can use event delegation:

```
$("#my_ok_div").on('click', '.okay', function () {
   alert('all okay!');
});
```

Comment: The above code assigns a click event to all `.okay` inside the parent `#my_ok_div`, rather than just all `.okay`. The following wouldn't have worked on your dynamically added divs. `$("#my_ok_div .okay").on('click', function () {alert('all okay!');});`

Comment: @SimonHartigan is that a correct to my answer?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Your answer was correct. I was only adding commentary as I felt it wasn't well explained to someone who might not understand, such as @flinth

Comment: @SimonHartigan what is better .on() or .live() ? I find another solution with live.

Comment: @flinth `.on` is better because `.live` will be removed in future a jQuery version.

Comment: @ExplosionPills oh I don't know about that, but on jQuery api live is better for my case: .live() - Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future. But if .on is for now and in the future too? Or i'll have problem with more divs or mm i don't clear understand it. Thanks

Comment: @flinth the example I gave you with `.on` is identical

Comment: Don't use live(), as @ExplosionPills mentioned, live() will be removed. The example above using on() does the same thing as what live would do. See my first comment as to why this happens.